# jquery - make trigger click X times

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I'm working with the function:

```
$('.box').on('click', '.goTo1', function(e) {
    $('.yar').trigger('click');
});
```

This works fine, but how could i register multiple clicks?

```
$('.yar').trigger('click');
$('.yar').trigger('click'); 
$('.yar').trigger('click');
```

I've tried the above, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas, maybe something like

`$('.yar').trigger(('click')2);`

Comment: If you have to trigger multiple clicks, there is probably a flaw in your application. What are you trying to do?

Comment: execute another function that is activated by clicking an element

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that. But why would you need to trigger a click 3 times on a single element?

Comment: because every time that element is clicked a function is executed. I need that function to execute a certain number of times. think about a 'next' button on an image slider. clicking something like 'jump ahead 5' would essentially click the 'next' button 5 times. or maybe it could be for something that adds 5, 10, 15 to something depending on which trigger is clicked. it doesn't have to make sense. i just want to get creative and have trigger click trigger another click X amount of times because I'm having fun and i can't find a solution anywhere and this is the place to go.

Comment: When you say *"the code above didnt work"*, do you mean repeating the trigger 3 times did not trigger 3 clicks? Or that worked, it's the last line of code which is not working? In other word, are you searching to remove the repetition or the current code is not working?

Comment: @GhostEcho it has to make sense to us indeed. We are here to help, and if you are going to a direction where you try do build up things in a wrong way, then we'll try to avoid to make yourself a buggy, bloated function. Your example with the slider makes sense, but would be a very bad way. I suggest you edit your OP with what exactly you are trying to achieve and we will help you with a good way of doing it.

Comment: I found the super simple solution i was after...surprised no one suggested it. see below if curious. thanks to everyone!

Comment: @GhostEcho no one suggested that because not because it works means its right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` works perfect for my situation. No need to create and modify numerous functions or use increments.

```
$('.box').on('click', '.goTo1', function(e) {
    $('.yar').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function() {$('.yar').trigger('click')},
    100);
});
```

hope this helps someone else

Comment: so and when you need 5 clicks you copy and paste the `setTimeout` within your click?

Comment: I only need two, but that should also work. Not the best solution but probably the most simple.

Comment: It's hard to understand how this solves your problem when this seems to do something totally different from what you described in your original post.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there's nothing like, `$('.yar').trigger(('click')2)`. You could just use a loop, e.g.,

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $(".yar").trigger("click");
}
```

But I'd stress Karl-André's question: what's the goal here? It sounds like a round-about way to solve some other problem in your code.

Comment: a function is executed when a click occurs, i need that function execute X amount of times. Plus, now I just want to see if it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

You example works. I guess it depends what is executed on the click function of .yar.
And triggering click event multiple times is a bad decision, doing so gives the vision that something is very bad in your code.

```js
$('.box').on('click', '.goTo1', function(e) {
    $('.yar').trigger('click');
    $('.yar').trigger('click');
    $('.yar').trigger('click');
});


$('.yar').on('click', function(){
    $(this).append('<p>event</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
    <div class="goTo1">GO TO</div>
</div>

<div class="yar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt it's a good way for whatever you are trying to achieve, but you could do:

```
$('.box').on('click', '.goTo1', function(e) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) $('.yar').trigger('click'); 
});
```

The variable `i` is the counter which defines how often the function gets called. If you want to fire the function `10` times you just replace `i < 3` with `i < 10`.

Comment: My code was copied wrong, it's the same element to be clicked on multiple times. thanks tho!

Comment: @GhostEcho why would you trigger the click of the same element more than one time? Please try to explain and we can help you better.

Comment: great idea, but i found a different solution